# Railsのscaffold_controllerで複数行を一気にcreateする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。
今、機能として例えば出版社を一個登録するとその出版社で出版された本が自動的に登録されることを作ろうとしています。
つまりCompaniesテーブルとBooksテーブルがあるという時、
BooksはCompaniesのIdを持っていることにします。
あと、会社登録画面で会社を1個登録します。会社の情報には何冊出版されたかの情報が入ってます。会社を登録すると何冊出版されたかのデータを利用してその分Booksに本を登録する感じです。

company, bookのモデルがあって
companies_controllerがあります。
今自分のcompanies_controllerのcreateの中には以下のように書いてあります。

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_params)

  if @company.save
    # company_paramsのbook_numを利用してその分だけbookにデータを入れたい。
    @book = Book.new

    if @book.save
      redirect_to @company, notice: 'successfully created.'
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく`Company`と`Book`はhas_many/belongs_toの関係だろうな、と想像します。

`Book`に登録する情報は`Company`が持っているものだけなのであれば、モデルの方のコールバックで登録するのがいいのかなと思います。

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

  after_create :create_books

  private
  def create_books
    self.book_num.times do
      self.books.create!({column1: self.some_column}) rescue raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

`Book`に登録すべき情報がフォームから渡されるのであれば、`book_num`の件数という要件からは少し外れますが、 Nested Model Form/Nested Attributesを利用する方法があります。ここで説明するには少々長くなるので、[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast)など既存の情報を探してみてください。

Comment: @Kim  Bookモデルの適当なコールバックで登録するのがよいでしょう。これ以上の回答が必要なのであれば、質問を編集して追記するか新たに別の質問として投稿してください。